# WooCommerce Backorders Filter on Variations

Tags: woocommerce

The below filter is supposed to check on a custom field value representing supplier stock and if it is above zero then allow for backorders.

The `is_array()` function was needed as the variable products appear to store the stock values in an array but I have debugged this and the correct value is being returned for the _supplier_stock i.e. a number above 0.

It works without issue for the simple products but not for the variable products.

Any ideas?

```
/*
* Supplier stock levels backorders allowed if there is supplier stock
*/
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_backorders','filter_woocommerce_product_get_backorders', 0, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_backorders', 'filter_woocommerce_product_get_backorders', 0, 2);
function filter_woocommerce_product_get_backorders( $backorders_status, $product ){   

    $supplier_stock = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_supplier_stock', true );

    if(is_array($supplier_stock)) {
        $supplier_stock = $supplier_stock[$product->get_id()];
    }    

    if ( ! empty ( $supplier_stock ) && $supplier_stock > 0 ) {
        $backorders_status = 'notify';       
    } 

    return $backorders_status; 
}
```

Comment: The first step you should check is if you just use `return 'notify';` in the callback function (without if conditions, get meta..) whether this works for both product types, if it does, you can extend your code, if not.. then you know the problem is elsewhere than with these hooks. Also please tell us more about that custom field, how and where was it added? and what is the result of that array? what does it look like?

Comment: @7uc1f3r hmmm, not even the basic function is working, very odd as I had it working on simple products at one point.

Comment: @7uc1f3r weirdly it jumps in to life when I save the product. Any ideas?